# Why is this program timing out without any network traffic?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to create a simple c++ program that hides the differences between Linux and Windows when making sockets and connecting to servers

The Linux part of this code compiles without any warnings or errors but times out  after resolving the host IP and does not connect to the server running (`nc -lvnp 7777`)

Using `tcpdump -i eth0 -v port 7777` to capture all the traffic to and from the machine running the program shows nothing

```cpp
class Socket
{
    public:
    int initsoc(void);

    int connectsoc(int sock, const char * host, int port);

};

int Socket::connectsoc(int sock, const char * host, int port)
    #ifdef _WIN32
        /* windows part */
    #else

        struct hostent *server;
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
        struct in_addr *address;

        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port = port;

        /* resolve host */
        
        server = gethostbyname(host);
        if (server == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error : %s \nFailed to resolve %s:%d", strerror(errno), host, port);
            return -1;
        }


        address = (struct in_addr *) (server->h_addr);
        printf("Resolved: [%s] ===> [%s]\n", host, inet_ntoa(*address));        
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*address));
        iResult = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
        printf("Connect returned : %d\n",iResult);
        if (iResult < 0)
        {
            printf("Error: %s\nFailed to connect\n",strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        printf("Connected to [%s:%d]\n",host,port);
        
        return 0;
```

I tried to open a netcat listener on a machine on the same network as the computer running the program without any NATs but it still times out

this is how i compiled and what it outputs

```
g++ -Wall -ggdb3 -pedantic -g main.cpp  -o app 
Resolved: [10.0.0.100] ===> [10.0.0.100]
Connect returned : -1
Error: Connection timed out
Failed to connect
```

the ip of the machine running the code is 10.0.0.2

the ip of the machine running the netcat server is 10.0.0.100

Comment: If you are doing this for learning purpose then it is OK, otherwise i recommend you to kindly look into [`Boost.ASIO`](https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioStandalone.html) library. There is a stand alone version which doesn't require entire Boost library. It is battle tested and has very nice documentation.

Comment: `perror` is your friend.

Comment: Does the ping to the server IP work?

Comment: How are you calling `Socket::connectsoc()`? Can you please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you forgot htons(port)

Comment: @Aamir  it is a class just create  an object and call the methods

Comment: @WeedCookie Using `inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*address))` is redundant, since `*address` is already in the necessary format. Use `server_addr.sin_addr = *address;` or `server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = address->s_addr;` instead. However, `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, use `getaddrinfo()` instead. That would also solve your `port` mistake, as `getaddrinfo()` will give you a properly and fully formed `sockaddr_in` that you can then give as-is to `connect()`

Comment: @kiner_shah yes it does respond to a ping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by @user253751](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626664/why-is-this-program-timing-out-without-any-network-traffic#comment128293362_72626664), this line:

`server_addr.sin_port = port;`

should be changed to:

`server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);`